# How to restart an Android Activity?

Tags: android, application-restart, android-launcher

I am creating an application in Android,  but when I would like to update some data, I want to restart my MainActivity. But my problem when I try to restart my Application, it crashes.

I use the following code to restart my Activity

```
 case R.id.update:
        admin = false;
        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
         finish();
         startActivity(intent1);    
        break;
```

my Log is

```
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package_____________/package________.LauncherGridActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at com.___________.ApplicationManager.loadFilteredNames(ApplicationManager.java:228)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at com______.ApplicationManager.loadApplications(ApplicationManager.java:65)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at co___.LauncherGridActivity.onCreate(LauncherGridActivity.java:142)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-22 12:28:10.444: E/AndroidRuntime(11867):    ... 11 m
```

Comment: Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent1); finish();

Comment: Something is wrong with `loadFilteredNames()` method in your code, when you restart. Post that code.

Comment: at com.___________.ApplicationManager.loadFilteredNames(ApplicationManager.java:228)

Some variable is null at this line .Make sure  you initialize it  before using .
I used the above same code to restart and it worked fine. So perhaps the problem is with a null variable.Pls post the above specified line

Comment: I think you have a design flaw with your system as a whole. You do not need to restart activity to reload data. That simply is not how it's done.

Comment: Correct, as Mr Budius is saying, to update your data only, don't finish and startActivity again and again, its heavy task for Android system, its this process Activity manager, Task Manager everything will be included, find another way to update data only, if you can tell the scenario we can help you in how to update data of activity instead of recreating it

Comment: There's something wrong here. I use the exact code that user1621629 posted and it works perfectly for me. Something's missing.

Comment: But that said, Budius is right; you don't normally need to restart an activity like this. I only do it when I change my app's theme.

Answer (score 1):

Use this you can restart activity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

But as per your requirement you need to recreate activity using `this.recreate();`

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this,YourActivityName.class);

startActivity(intent);

finish();
```