# 2 MainActivities after Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity

My app should be opened after the broadcast receiver operation. But if my app opens at the current moment I need to delete the previous MainActivity and create a new MainActivity. How to start MainActivity from broadcast receiver and delete the previous MainActivity if the activity starts before?

Broadcast:

```
Intent initialIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.cc.dd");
    initialIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    initialIntent.putExtra(Constants.NUMBER,getIncomingNumber(mCallState));
    context.startActivity(initialIntent);
```

I tried to use flags but I  have strange logs:

> D/CallReceiver: main: [RINGING]
>   D/CallReceiver: main: [Incoming call true]
>   D/MainActivity: main: [ON_PAUSE]
>   D/MainActivity: main: [ON_CREATE]
>   D/MainActivity: main: [ON_START]
>   D/MainActivity: main: [ON_RESUME]

I see the  MainActivity previous version goes to onPause and  the  new version starts. Why the previous version doesn't delete?

Comment: you can add `android:launchMode = "singleInstance"` to your activity tag in manifest. That ensures that your activity is only opened once....

Comment: what is the issue you are facing

Comment: So if you want to kill all the previous activities, just follow these methods. In API level 11 or greater, use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag on Intent to clear all the activity stack.
initialIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


Another way is android:launchMode= "singleInstance" how Opiatefuchs said.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call finish() if you want to end an activity's life-cycle. Following code will simply restart the current activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

References:

- [How do I restart an Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)
- [How to restart an Android Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145056/how-to-restart-an-android-activity)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add:

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

to your activity tag in manifest. That ensures that your activity is only opened once. Example:

```
<activity
android:name=".YourActivity"
android:label="@string/your_activity_name"
android:launchMode = "singleInstance" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot delete previous activity.You can add flag **singleInstance** for your activity.